# What is 'Rising of the lights' as a death?

Tags: lungs, death, history

In a reddit post showing the '[Causes of death of london in 1632](https://www.reddit.com/r/interestingasfuck/comments/f4cu65/causes_of_death_in_1632_london/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share)' Theres a few causes that seem weird.

But the one the caught my attention is 'Rising of the lights'. The best I've seen is that [Lights = Lungs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rising_of_the_lights), but still Rising of the lungs seems to go nowhere.

So what is a Rising of the lights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Glossary of Old Medical Terms](https://www.thornber.net/medicine/html/medgloss.html) by Craig Thornber:

> Rising of the Lights:  croup - any obstructive condition of the larynx or trachea (windpipe), characterised by a hoarse, barking cough and difficult breathing, occurring chiefly in infants and children.

which backs up the speculations in [Correspondence in the British Medical Journal, Dec 1926](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2523749/pdf/brmedj08355-0057b.pdf).

[Croup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croup) is a respiratory condition:

> Croup, also known as laryngotracheobronchitis, is a type of respiratory infection that is usually caused by a virus. The infection leads to swelling inside the trachea, which interferes with normal breathing and produces the classic symptoms of "barking" cough, stridor, and a hoarse voice. Fever and runny nose may also be present.

Comment: As you noted, croup is usually caused by a virus. More specifically, it's typically caused by parainfluenza, which is part of the paramyxovirus family.